# C/C++ - Iteration counter for Newton's Method

Tags: c++, c, function, printf

I have created a function that runs Newton's Method for approximating the solution to a function (defined as f). My function returns the better approximation for the root just fine, however it will not display the number of iterates performed in the function properly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

double newton(double x_0, double newtonaccuracy);

double f(double x);

double f_prime(double x);

int main() 
{
   double x_0;  

   double newtonaccuracy;  

   int converged;  

   int iter;

   printf("Enter the initial estimate for x : ");

   scanf("%lf", &x_0);

   _flushall();

   printf("\n\nEnter the accuracy required : ");

   scanf("%lf", &newtonaccuracy);

   _flushall();


   if (converged == 1) 
      {
        printf("\n\nNewton's Method required %d iterations for accuracy to %lf.\n", iter, newtonaccuracy);

        printf("\n\nThe root using Newton's Method is x = %.16lf\n", newton(x_0, newtonaccuracy));
      } 

   else 
      {
        printf("Newton algorithm didn't converge after %d steps.\n", iter);
      }



      system("PAUSE");
} 


double newton(double x_0, double newtonaccuracy) 
{
   double x = x_0;

   double x_prev;

   int iter = 0;


   do 
   {
      iter++;


      x_prev = x;

      x = x_prev - f(x_prev)/f_prime(x_prev);

   } 
   while (fabs(x - x_prev) > newtonaccuracy && iter < 100);

   if (fabs(x - x_prev) <= newtonaccuracy)
   {
      int converged = 1;
   }  
   else
   {
      int converged = 0; 
   }   




    return x;
}  


double f(double x) {
       return ( cos(2*x) - x );
}  

double f_prime(double x) 
{
   return ( -2*sin(2*x)-1 ); 
}
```

To be as specific as possible, it is the line:

```
printf("\n\nNewton's Method required %d iterations for accuracy to %lf.\n", iter, newtonaccuracy);
```

that is giving me trouble. Every time I run this program it says "Newton's Method required 2686764 iterations..." however this can't be true, provided I have coded correctly (the max number of iterations my code allows is 100).

Answer (score 2):

The variable `iter` used in `main` is not initialized or used in the `newton` function, where you use a local variable `iter`. You need to either pass `iter` to `newton` by reference or find a way to return it from the function.

Here is an example of a function taking some parameters by reference and modifying them:

```
double foo(double& initial_value, int& iterations)
{
  initial_value *= 3.14159;
  iterations = 42;
  return initial_value/2.;
}
```

From the caller side:

```
double x + 12345.;
int iter = 0;
double y = foo(initial_value, iter);
```

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for your reply. What is the most straightforward way to do this? I know I can't use return, as that's already used for giving x. I am only getting used to programming! (Also, I see that I have made the same mistake with "converged"). If you would have a similar method of dealing with this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @juanchopanza I appreciate your elaboration, but I have trouble relating your example to what I'm trying to do. Would you mind explaining in relation to my code what needs to be done to at least display the number of iterates properly?

Comment: @Mel change your `newton` function to take `iter` and `converged` by reference, and **do not** re-define them inside the body of the function. You might want to make `converged` a `bool` instead of an `int` too.